# JavaScript - Clientside separation of Model and ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

I [already asked this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325386/javascript-clientside-seperation-of-model-and-viewmodel) on a different site, but since it barely got any attention (let alone an answer), I hoped it might fit in here.

I am developing web apps using the Model-View-ViewModel approach with Knockout.js. After reading on the [original introduction of MVVM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johngossman/2005/10/08/introduction-to-modelviewviewmodel-pattern-for-building-wpf-apps/) by John Gossman, I realized that my ViewModel always contains ALL the app's logic, not only UI logic, but everything.

I've read somewhere that with Knockout, the model is considered the database or generally the data on the server. But according to MVC, the model also contains functions which do some processing with that data and are not UI-related.

So I wondered if it would be reasonable to have a separate Model object, independent from the ViewModel object? The idea behind this would be that the ViewModel would contain UI logic only (as intended by Gossman) and the Model would contain business logic only (as in MVC), which has nothing to do with the actual View. Example:

```
var viewModel = {
    hint: ko.observable("idle"), //text visible in the View
    buttonClicked: function () {
        this.hint("doing stuff");
        model.doStuff();
        this.hint("done");
    }
};

var model = {
    doStuff: function () {
        //business logic, UI independent
    }
};
```

Is there a recommendation or "best practice" which can be derived from the MVVM pattern definition?

Comment: I can´t tell if it´s considered best practise or if it is derived from any pattern, but this "architecture" you described is very convinient especially in larger projects, since the logic in model itself does only specific functionality for the model, which can be used repeatadly in multiple viewmodels for different purposees. Separating the logic for model and viewmodel will definitely do no harm

Comment: To me it's not a best practise, it's almost a requirement. When your logic goes complex, your viewmodels turn unreadable if you don't split business logic and UI logic.
In addition, it makes error management easier, as it separates layers

Answer (score 1):

I think it gets a little fuzzy to try and have data-only models separate from viewModels, because ViewModels can contain 'derived' columns and such that blur the line between the 'model' and what the view needs in the 'viewModel'

I typically use classes (forget how you classify them) to *encapsulate* the transformations from real server-side models to the viewModels my view will use... including derived columns (e.g. FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName), data transformations (e.g. date formatting), and functions that I make available for manipulation of the viewModel.

So really, you end up having nested *classes* (each a 'viewModel' in its own right) to encapsulate complex entities and keep the transformations/functions organized together with the entities they are associated with. Note that functions that manipulate arrays are attached one level higher than the entities in that collection that they modify.

So a books view Model might look something like:

```
MainVM:
  Authors: observableArray
  AddAuthor: function
  RemoveAuthor: function

Author class: 
  FirstName
  LastName
  FullName: (derived)
  Books: observableArray
  AddBook: function
  RemoveBook: function

Book class: 
  Title
  ISBN
  PublishDate (function to format raw date)
```

Furthermore, UI logic (anything that does DOM stuff or Jquery, for example) doesn't belong anywhere here... but in custom bindingHandlers or knockout extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more helpful to think of Knockout as being neatly divided between Specification and Implementation. The HTML file completely specifies the application, both in terms of appearance and behavior. The bindings specify an interface that you have to implement to make the application work.

Everything on the JavaScript side - your viewmodel and any custom bindings, and any underlying code - is about implementing the specified interface. How you break the tasks down is entirely an implementation detail. Good programming practices say that if you have routines that will be useful in multiple places, particularly if they might be useful in other projects, you should make a library of them. That seems to apply to business logic generally.